# Regex: How to valid domain part not in email have all numeric

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with one issue where I need to verify domain part should not all be numeric.

For example:
abc@123.com -> Invalid
abc@1abc.com -> valid

Regex:

```
^(?=(.{1,64}@.{1,255}))((?!.*?[._]{2})[!#$%&'*+\-\/=?\^_`{|}~a-zA-Z0-9}]{1,64}(\.[!#$%&'*+\-\/=?\^_`{|}~a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}(?<!\.)){0,})@((\[(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\])|((?!-)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)(\.(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)){1,}))$
```

Above regex need modification because there are some other validation which is working fine with above regex. Only thing is pending to validate domain part should not all numeric.

Updated:

After some research on above regex
I am able to segregate emails in to different groups. Now for group 10 need to add validation if all characters in group 10 string are aplha numeric.

Regex:

```
^(?=(.{1,64}@.{1,255}))((?!.*?[._]{2})[!#$%&'*+\-\/=?\^_`{|}~a-zA-Z0-9}]{1,64}(\.[!#$%&'*+\-\/=?\^_`{|}~a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}(?<!\.)){0,})@((\[(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\])|((?!-)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])((?:.*[a-zA-Z0-9]))[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,63}(?<!-)(\.(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)){1,}))$
```

Explore regex on : https://regex101.com/

TIA

Comment: JAVA is not JavaScript. I removed it since you also added the unnecessary Angular tag

Comment: There are numeric domains in the wild

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in doing this - the fact that an email fulfills the requirements as set forth in RFC5322 does not mean it's a valid email address: The only way to know that, is to send an email to it, and have the user reply to it, follow a link inside it, or copy a code/token inside it.

Given that you have to do that anyway, that will also pick up any issues with invalid email addresses. Thus, the correct validation for email is:

```
Pattern.compile("^.+@.+\\..+$")
```

(Assuming you don't want single

and this does what you want, which is, filter out obvious incorrect entries, and that's all you need.

If you insist in continuing your mistake, there's always [emailregex.com](https://emailregex.com), which has the regex and explains how it works.

NB: Note that you're just wrong. `12345@678.cde` can easily be valid - `com` may not allow you to register a domain that consists solely of digits, but it's not an inherent limitation of the DNS system: Domain parts can be all numbers. The top level domain cannot be, at least, for now, but any other part of it can be. Thus, rejecting `foo@123.com` is only possible if you program in, on a per-TLD basis, the exact rules. Which also means you need to sign up to the mailing list of every TLD operator to check for any changes they make. You'll be updating that regex every other week. Told you it's a silly thing to want to do!

Comment: Thank you for looking into it @rzwitserloot. But this is some requirement and we need to fix this. Regex I added in question is working for all our scenario only requirement is pending that numeric part validation. There are some short of restriction like we need to use above regex.

Comment: .com does allow numeric domains, such as 163.com

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We are following RFC rules for email validation. Could you please share any reference link which explains only numeric are allowed in domain part? We need a trusted resource to confirm our client hence need a reference. Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 0):

u can use this to detect the invalid ones.

```
^\w+([-+.']\w+)*+@\d+.com
```

just change the .com to which postfix you like.

Comment: Thank you for looking. Can you please help me to incorporate the changes in above regex (mention in question).